# How to diagnose a program run by the user from a program run by Windows(run on windows startup)in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, startup, app-startup

i have a wpf program that can run in windows startup. i want to run
program in `WindowState.Normal` mode when user run the program and
in `WindowState.Minimized` when windows run the program at startup. but problem
is that i do not know how to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use a launcher app, an app's who's sole purpose is to launch your main application with a command line argument that says that the user launched it. If that command line argument is there, it was launched by the launcher and you can show it in normal mode. If the argument isn't there it was launched by the OS and run it minimized.

Comment: So i will use this commands to start the main program.

`ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\etc\Program Files\ProgramFolder\Program.exe";
Process.Start(startInfo);`
but how i can pass a parameter to the main program? and how to get this parameter in the main program?

Comment: You use [ProcessStartInfo.Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx), and you can read it in WPF [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970914(v=vs.100).aspx).